# A simple(r) proof from inequality on nat to bool

Tags: coq

While doing the exercises of the [Software Foundations](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html) I needed a derivation as expressed by the theorem `not_eq_nat__beq_nat_false` below. After struggling for a while with various tactics and standard theorems, I gave up and settled for using the theorem below.

I still feels however that there should be a much simpler way of proving this. Its dual `eq_nat__beq_nat_true` for example is much simpler.

```
Require Export Arith.
Require Export Arith.EqNat.

Theorem ex_falso_quodlibet : forall (P:Prop), False -> P.
Proof.
  intros P contra.
  inversion contra.
Qed.

Theorem not_eq_nat__beq_nat_false: forall n m : nat
, n <> m -> (n =? m) = false
.
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold not in H.
  destruct (n =? m) eqn:beqval; try reflexivity.
  apply ex_falso_quodlibet. apply H.
  apply beq_nat_true; assumption.
Qed.

Theorem eq_nat__beq_nat_true: forall n m : nat
, n = m -> (n =? m) = true
.
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite H. symmetry. apply beq_nat_refl.
Qed.
```

My guess is that using a `sumbool` is the solution. How can such a triviality be easily proven?

By the answer of Vinz, the following was what I was looking for.

```
Theorem not_eq_nat__beq_nat_false: forall n m : nat
, n <> m -> (n =? m) = false
.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply beq_nat_false_iff. assumption.
Qed.

Theorem eq_nat__beq_nat_true: forall n m : nat
, n = m -> (n =? m) = true
.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply beq_nat_true_iff. assumption.
Qed.
```

Very simple indeed.

Comment: Usually I'd use an iff here a merge the two lemmas (even better, you can use reflect from the std lib)

Comment: `firstorder` is sometimes good at applying assumptions from the context, and doing tedious things like `intro` and `auto`.  In this particular case you can do (what amounts to Vinz's proof) simply with `induction n,m; firstorder.` If that's too much magic, just do `induction n,m; simpl; auto; congruence.`

Comment: @ejgallego, could you give an example of how to use `reflect`?

Comment: @larsr, sure, see https://x80.org/collacoq/ezegubacox.coq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your are use std lemmas such as `beq_nat_true`, then you could use `beq_nat_false_iff`. Otherwise, without any lemma from the std lib, I'd go for induction:

```
Theorem not_eq_nat__beq_nat_false: forall n m : nat
, n <> m -> beq_nat n m = false
.
Proof.
  induction n as [ | n hi]; intros [ | m] h; simpl in *; try reflexivity.
  - now elim h.
  - now apply hi; intro heq; apply h; rewrite heq.
Qed.
```